# Generating model by JeffreyWay Generators, can't specify the path

Tags: php, laravel-4

Every time I generate a model using Jeffrey Way's Generators library, the models gets created in the "app/" directory. For example, I've run the following:

```
php artisan generate:model vision
```

This gets created in the "app/" directory.

I would like to have the model get created in a "models" directory, so I tried this:

```
php artisan generate:model --path="models" vision
```

However, I get the following error:

```
file_put_contents(models/Vision.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory


generate:model [--path="..."] [--templatePath="..."] modelName
```

How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: Do you have a "models" directory in your framework root? If not, I believe it needs to be created first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this version of the library, it appears that the specified path must exist before using it. I was able to replicate your experience as shown below:

```
[chris@little-mac:four-dot-two]$ php artisan generate:model vision
Created: /Users/chris/Projects/four-dot-two/app/models/Vision.php
[chris@little-mac:four-dot-two]$ php artisan generate:model --path="models" vision



  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_put_contents(models/Vision.php): failed to open stream: No such file o  
  r directory                                                                  



generate:model [--path="..."] [--templatePath="..."] modelName
```

To resolve it, I simply created a "models" directory at the framework root.

```
[chris@little-mac:four-dot-two]$ mkdir models
[chris@little-mac:four-dot-two]$ php artisan generate:model --path="models" vision
Created: models/Vision.php
[chris@little-mac:four-dot-two]$
```

Comment: I do already have a directory models at framework root and I have the other models inside.

Comment: @YousefAltaf That models directory is _not_ in your framework root; your framework root is "elarabiaLaravel". It looks like the folders in your framework root are "app", "bootstrap", "public" and "vendor"

Comment: @YousefAltaf Just to clarify, calling `generate:model` stores the model within "app/models/" by default; they're getting stored in the models folder within your app directory.

Comment: I can't understand this shouldn't the models directory placed in the app directory, sorry I bit new to this framework, or just create the model and then move it inside?

Comment: Got it so I just did `php artisan generate:model --path="app/models" vision` and it's done thanks

Comment: @YousefAltaf Yep; and you can honestly remove the "`--path="app/models"` part; it stores models to that path by default.